# Intuitive/geometric way of thinking about effective divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

> What is the motivation/intuition/geometric way of thinking about an effective divisor?

I know that a divisor is effective if all its coefficients are non-negative. We write $D \ge 0$ for effective divisors. We can extend this in the obvious manner to get a partial ordering of divisors.

I would consider any explanation that introduces the concepts of Weil and/or Cartier divisors to be obfuscating the underlying intuition of the definition in more formalism...

Comment: Actually, if you think about a divisor as a Weil divisor (which you cannot always do, though), you should see that an effective divisor is just a union of irreducible varieties of codimension $1$ (counted with the respective multiplicities). This is actually why they are called *effective*.

Comment: For example, consider a Riemann surface (which is a smooth complex curve). Then a Weil divisor is just a finite sum of points, with sign. The effective divisors are those that you can actually *see* on your curve.

Comment: It might help get answers useful to you specifically if you elaborate how you think of divisors.

Comment: Restricting ourselves to the factorial case, where there is no Weil/Cartier distinction: effective divisors are cut out by regular sections of line bundles, while general divisors are cut out by rational sections. Also, I should maybe mention that something clicked in my head when I noticed that the Spanish term for cash is "dinero efectivo."

Comment: I'm almost certain that "Matt E" has some answers along these lines on this site. A little too lazy to dig them up right now myself though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An effective divisor is just a formal linear combination of codimension one subvarieties of some scheme. The best way to understand that statement is with an example. Consider a quartic surface
$$
X = \textbf{Proj}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]}{(x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4)}\right)
$$
Notice if we take any homogeneous polynomial in the quotient ring defining $X$, we get a codimension one subscheme. Notice I stated subscheme and not subvariety here, this is intentional. If we consider the divisor $D$ of $X$ as a subscheme given by
$$
\textbf{Proj}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]}{(x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4, x^4(2x^2 + 3x)(x^2 + y^2)^2)}\right)
$$
then we can write it as
$$
D = 4[x] + [2x^2 + 3x] + 2[x^2 + y^2]
$$
So we've kept the topological information inside the brackets and moved the scheme theoretic information outside of the brackets and turned it into the coefficients of our divisor. If you really wanted, you could write down $X_i$'s as proj's of these graded rings, but I leave this as an exercise for the reader.